# How do I code on pyomo (python), for index[i] not to be equal to index[j]

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am trying to code an optimization problem that reads distance matrix data from an excel sheet shown below.

[image]

I have a parameter for the distance between nodes i and j.

`model.D = Param(model.I, model.J, domain = PositiveReals)    # Distance between nodes`

However, I don't want it to read the values for D(1,1), D(2,2), D(3,3) and so on as they are a value of 0 and parameter D is in the domain of Positive Reals.

The below is the error message I am getting.

```
    RuntimeError: Failed to set value for param=D, index=(1.0, 1.0),
    value=0.0.
    source error message=Invalid parameter value: D[(1.0, 1.0)] = '0.0',
    value type=<class 'float'>. Value not in parameter domain PositiveReals
```

Is there some way I code this so that index [i] cannot equal index [j] and I will get past this error?

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with 2 techniques....  some hybrid of this is probably your best bet.  I like to create the set of "legal routes" (which is `model.IJ` and `model.IJ_2` in this example because it tends to come in handy for constraints, etc.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

data = {(1, 1): 0.0,
        (1, 2): 1.5,
        (1, 3): 2.1,
        (2, 1): 1.4,
        (2, 2): 0.0,
        (2, 3): 1.9,
        (3, 1): 1.3,
        (3, 2): 2.9,
        (3, 3): 0.0}

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.I = pyo.Set(initialize=list({t[0] for t in data.keys()}))
model.J = pyo.Set(initialize=list({t[1] for t in data.keys()}))

# method 1:  make a set of legal combinations (routes)
model.IJ = pyo.Set(within=model.I*model.J, initialize = [(i, j) for i in model.I for j in model.J if i != j])
def dist_initializer(model, i, j):
    return data[i, j]
model.dist_1 = pyo.Param(model.IJ, rule=dist_initializer)

# method 2:  prune your dataset
data_2 = {(i, j):d for (i, j), d in data.items() if i != j}
model.IJ_2 = pyo.Set(initialize=data_2.keys())
model.dist_2 = pyo.Param(model.IJ_2, initialize=data_2)

model.pprint()
```

#### Yields:

```
5 Set Declarations
    I : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {1, 2, 3}
    IJ : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain    : Size : Members
        None :     2 : IJ_domain :    6 : {(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)}
    IJ_2 : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    Any :    6 : {(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)}
    IJ_domain : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    I*J :    9 : {(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)}
    J : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {1, 2, 3}

2 Param Declarations
    dist_1 : Size=6, Index=IJ, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key    : Value
        (1, 2) :   1.5
        (1, 3) :   2.1
        (2, 1) :   1.4
        (2, 3) :   1.9
        (3, 1) :   1.3
        (3, 2) :   2.9
    dist_2 : Size=6, Index=IJ_2, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key    : Value
        (1, 2) :   1.5
        (1, 3) :   2.1
        (2, 1) :   1.4
        (2, 3) :   1.9
        (3, 1) :   1.3
        (3, 2) :   2.9

7 Declarations: I J IJ_domain IJ dist_1 IJ_2 dist_2
[Finished in 248ms]
```